# How to link OpenCl library to Clion IDE

Tags: c++, opencl

I am writing a HellowWorld example using opencl library in Clion.
My problem is problem is that i get the error message

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable HelloWorldOpencl
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpencl.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/belkacem/CLionProjects/HelloWorldOpencl/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpencl.dir/build.make:84: HelloWorldOpencl] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/HelloWorldOpencl.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

my opencl is installed correctly in the following directiries

```
libOpenCL1 - OpenCL ICD Bindings

/etc/alternatives/libOpenCL.so.1
/usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1
/usr/lib64/ocl-icd
/usr/lib64/ocl-icd/libOpenCL.so.1
/usr/lib64/ocl-icd/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
/usr/share/doc/packages/libOpenCL1
/usr/share/doc/packages/libOpenCL1/README

7 files total
```

How i can link the library with Clion IDE?

Comment: I've just noticed that you use `cmake`. Can you please post your `CMakLists.txt` file here?

Answer (score 0):

Your OpenCL installation might be incomplete - you should have a library `libOpenCL.so` somewhere, and also at least one ICD file in the `/etc/OpenCL/vendors` directory.

Comment: thank you for reply , i check /etc/OpenCL/vendors directory and there is ICD file, (i open the ICD file here is the content /usr/lib64/beignet//libcl.so

Comment: The ICD file is read by the `libOpenCL.so` library, and it looks like this library is absent on your machine. I don't work with the Beignet OpenCL, so it's difficult for me to help you. However, on my machine the library `libOpenCL.so` does exist (it's actually a symlink to the `libOpenCL.so.1.0.0`), and it's a part of the `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` package. May be, it makes sense to install this package? Happy New Year